# SQL search not returning any output?

Tags: php, sql, search

I have looked in every possible forum and question page and still cant understand why my sql search is not returning any values. It is written in a PHP script which is designed to search for the name that user has entered on the HTML page and return all the columns in the database.

Please note that i am fairly new to learning PHP and SQl so please dont hate if this is just me being stupid haha.

Thanks in advance,
Chris

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <?php
            $ServerName = "****";
            $LogInUN = "*****";
            $LogInPW = "******";
            $DBName = "********";

            $Connection = mysqli_connect($ServerName, $LogInUN, $LogInPW, $DBName);

            if(!$Connection){
              die("<p>Connection error!</p>" . mysqli_connect_error());
            }

            $Name = mysqli_real_escape_string($Connection, $_POST['Name']);

            $Query = "SELECT Firstname FROM Students WHERE Firstname LIKE '%{%Name}%'";

            $result = $Connection->query($Query);

                        echo $result;
                        echo $Name;

        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `echo $result;` you can't just do that.

Comment: How could i do that then?

Answer (score 1):

Use $Name

```
$Query = "SELECT Firstname FROM Students WHERE Firstname LIKE '%{$Name}%'";
```

After `$result = $Connection->query($Query);` Line write below lines

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                       echo $row["Firstname"];
                        echo $Name;
}
```

Remove `$result = $Connection->query($Query);` and use

```
$result = mysqli_query($Connection, $Query);
```

Comment: It is still not returning anything?

Comment: Still isnt? Im not sure what it is doing?

Comment: after `$result = $Connection->query($Query);`  can you `echo mysqli_num_rows($result)` write this to how many rows you are getting from the query

Comment: change your $Query as above and other lines as above

Comment: The echo 'mysqli_num_rows($result);' returns 0 eventough mt db is populated

Comment: `SELECT Firstname FROM Students` use this statement in query and check you are getting any data or not

Comment: I have updates my code to this                         $Query = "SELECT Lastname FROM Students WHERE Firstname LIKE  '%{$Name}%'";

                        $result = mysqli_query($Connection, $Query);
                        echo mysqli_num_rows($result);

                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                        echo $row["Firstname"];
                        }

Comment: This only displays a number but not the actual result

Answer (score -1):

$Query = "SELECT Firstname FROM Students WHERE Firstname LIKE '%{%Name}%'";
use this
$Query = "SELECT Firstname FROM Students WHERE Firstname LIKE '%{$Name}%'";